# Request.get() return 403

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, http-status-code-403

I am fairly new to python and the web scarping. However, I tried to access one website using Request library, but getting 403 forbidden error. Can anyone help me to solve this?

`import requests`

`res = requests.get('https://en.aruodas.lt/butai/vilniuje/puslapis/1/', headers={ "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5", })`

`print(res)`

Thank you for your contribution

Comment: You get a 403 when you are trying to access a resource that requires authentication. Also, web scraping is a very bad idea and can lead you to legal issues.

Comment: It does not require anything, it detect the scraper as a bot that the issue. Its a very good idea since the website is publicaly available no legal issues.

Comment: @onlinejudge95, I get what you're trying to say by "web scraping is a very bad idea", but you should specify that is a bad idea only in certain circumstances, the important thing is to know when it is legal and when it isn't.

Comment: The URL in question always redirects to a Listing page. I don't think you should be scraping any website that you don't have control over or has a ROBOTS.txt defined. There is a reason why scraping is frowned upon. OP should instead use any public available APIs or a lawyer.